# Yii2 component function in view

Tags: php, yii, yii2, components, yii2-advanced-app

I have one view, in that view i need some direct query like below,

```
$count = Student::find()->where(['user_id'=>yii::$app->user->identity->id])->count();
```

But in yii2 documentation they are not recommended [this.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#best-practices)

So i am create component class for this and then call component function in view like below,

```
$count = Yii::$app->mycomponent->sCount();
```

MyComponent.php

```
<?php

 namespace app\components;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Component;
 use app\models\Student;

 class MyComponent extends Component
 {
  public function sCount()
  {
   $count =      Student::find()->where(['user_id'=>yii::$app->user->identity->id])->count();
   return $count;
  }
 }
?>
```

Here all are working fine i want to know this logic is correct or this also same like in first case. Please suggest correct way.

Answer (score 2):

If the code i largely used in several application and group a set of common funtionalities related  to a specified  logical area you can use  components 
but for application related  functionalties
In  MVC the correct way for this is perform  main procedural  code and db request in controllerAction 
and for function model's realted  the correct place should be the model itself or an extended  model as eg:  modelSearch for serach functions related to the mdels
an pass  the values  you need  to the view in render call eg:

so you could add  (or extend) you model ad add  the function

```
public function sCount()
{
  $count =      Student::find()->where(['user_id'=>yii::$app->user->identity->id])->count();
  return $count;
}
```

and refer to this function is you controller eg:

```
class MyController  extends Controller
{

  ......
    public function actionMyView($id)
    {

        $count = $model->sCount();
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'count' => $count,
        ]);
    }
```

then in view  you can refer to $count

```
  echo $count;
```

another valid solution for avoid  extra memory and CPU time to support event and behavior functionality  is the use of an helpers Class .. a  class for manage recurring code function not properly related  to  a single model

Comment: Thank you for response.I don't have any relation for both model, at the same time i want this function at several places in that application only, like main layout also.then component is fine?

Comment: yes  you can use component  .. but also a ìn helpers class .. the component have three main features Properties, Events, Behaviors  .. if you need  this the you need  component .. if not you can build an helpers class if the function is not related  to  model

Comment: Thank you so much scaisEdge :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can supply the count as this.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Student::find();
    $cloneQuery = clone $query;
    $count = $cloneQuery->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->count();
    $models = $query->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        'models' => $models,
        'count' => $count
    ]);
}
```

And access on you view like `$count`.
* there are a lot of ways to do. But you have to follow the best practices..